# C program involving call to functions(beginner) - I don't understand

Tags: c

currently I have a question at hand that I don't understand due to a few things. Here is the question:

Que. 1.    Given the following program, show the values of the variables a, b, c, x, y, z in the main function after each function call to FindSum. Also, show the values of a, b, c in FindSum immediately after executing each function call to FindSum.

And here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
/*   function prototype declaration for FindSum   */
void FindSum(int, int, int *);
int main(void)
{
    int a=2, b=5, c=1, x=3, y=4, z=7; 
    FindSum (a, b, &c);    /* a first call to FindSum   */  
    printf(“first call in main %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d \n”, a, b, c, x, y, z);  
    FindSum (x, y, &z);    /* a second call to FindSum   */
    printf(“second call in main %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d \n”, a, b, c, x, y, z); 
    return  0;
}

/*   definition of FindSum   */
void FindSum (int a, int b, int *c)
{
    a += (b * 2);
    b += (b * 2);
    *c += (b * 2);
    printf(“in FindSum: %d  %d  %d \n”, a, b, *c);
```

My questions:
1) Which one is the main function?
2) Is the problem asking me to finish up the code so that it produces the desired result?
3) Also, show the values of a, b, c in FindSum immediately after executing each function call to FindSum" Where is the function call to findsum

I'm currently in a C programming class where the professor doesn't explain well/english is subpar. Due to this, I am struggling slightly on these issues. Was hoping someone could shed me light

Comment: Except for the missing final `}`, this is a complete program, and the questions are essentially asking you to predict the output.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to [Google for a great book, *C Primer Plus*, by Steve Prata]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Primer_Plus). It shouldn't take more than 2 hours to power through the first three chapters, and functions will be simple. Be sure to learn the different between a "function definition" and a "function declaration/prototype". Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Which one is the main function?

The one named `main`.

> 2) Is the problem asking me to finish up the code so that it produces the desired result?

No, it's asking you to act like the computer and "run the program" on paper and say what it would output.

> 3) Also, "show the values of a, b, c in FindSum immediately after executing each function call to FindSum" Where is the function call to findsum

They're marked with comments in the code. Search for "call to FindSum".

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the basic structure of a program.  Including how functions work and the difference between pass by value and pass by reference.  Understanding this is key towards answering these questions.  The "int main(void)" line is the main function declaration.  The left and right brackets define it's scope.  Note the values of the variables a,b,c,x,y,&z at the beginning.  Write them on a piece of paper.  The FindSum function takes in two parameters and outputs one parameter.  Perform the calculation and write down your results.  This answers the first part of the question.  Then step through line of code and write down the results after each call to FindSum.  This is not asking for you to modify the code, but simply execute what the computer would compute.